When a foreground process is running and ssh connection is terminated,In default behavior The foreground Process receives SIGHUP,but mine kept running
In Ubuntu 22.04, foreground processes may not receive the SIGHUP signal when the terminal is closed, especially if they are backgrounded or detached. This behavior differs from expectations, where traditionally, the SIGHUP signal is sent to processes associated with the terminal upon closure.
This issue can lead to unintended consequences, such as processes continuing to run after the terminal is closed, which may not align with the user's intentions or expectations. It can impact scenarios where users expect processes to gracefully terminate upon terminal closure, ensuring proper resource management and cleanup.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
